# Azure AD B2C: Force password after 90 days

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

First of all, thanks much for [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-password-reset-after-90-days). Easy to follow and I was able to successfully try it out.

This question related to ClaimsTransformation "ComparePasswordResetOnWithCurrentDateTime" where it is determined if a password reset is required .

On line 77, would it be possible to pass a claim value for the Value attribute in the InputParameter tag ?

Please see screen shot attached
[image: screen shot]

If that's not possible, any ideas on how to accomplish the 'earlier than' operation, where the timeSpanInSeconds is based on a runtime value ?

Answer (score 0):

•   Since you are passing an input parameter value which is defined as an element for passing a constant value to a transformation which has two attributes, viz., Value that is the actual constant value to be passed and the ID that is used to give a unique name to the input as in which must match the expected inputs for the transformation method. As you have already given the input parameter as ‘timespaninseconds’ and data type as ‘int’ with a value of ‘80’ which is in line with the input parameter transformation method.

•   Thus, if you want to use a claim value instead of the hard coded value passed in that parameter string, then you use them as below example and modify them as per your requirement: -

```
‘ <ClaimsTransformation Id="ComparePasswordResetOnWithCurrentDateTime" 
     TransformationMethod="AssertDateTimeIsLessThan">
     <InputClaims>
     <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="approvedDateTime" 
     TransformationClaimType="leftOperand" />
     <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="currentDateTime" 
     TransformationClaimType="rightOperand" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
<InputParameter Id="AssertIfEqualTo" DataType="boolean" Value="false" />
<InputParameter Id="AssertIfRightOperandIsNotPresent" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
  <InputParameter Id="TimeSpanInSeconds" DataType="int" Value="-90" />
  </InputParameters>
  </ClaimsTransformation> ‘
```

In this claims transformation, if the value of current date and time is earlier than 90 and the approved date and time is equal to the current date and time, then the operation will be carried out to reset the password if the date and time are equal to or greater than 90 days.

Please refer the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/date-transformations

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-claims-mapping-policy-type

Comment: not sure i follow...i want to make 90 runtime value and not hard coded